# PHP change the decimal separator

Tags: php, decimal

In some circumstances PHP is changing the decimal separator after the operation, here is an example:

```
<?php    
echo $amount; //21.960000
echo $this->obj_vat->vat; //10.00
$amount= $amount + ( $amount * ( $this->obj_vat->vat / 100 ) );
echo $amount; //24,156
?>
```

Why the decimal separator changes to ','?

---

This is a multilanguage website. In the spanish version the locale is set to spanish (es_ES), and the decimal separator is ','. That's why is changing.

A solution is to force the LC_NUMERIC to english:

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, $locale );

setlocale( LC_NUMERIC, 'en_GB' );
```

But I don't know if this is a proper solution.

Comment: I tried the same I am getting 24.156

Comment: I don't know whats causing the problem everything is fine.

Comment: You forgot to say what version of PHP, what web server, what platform and how are you running PHP (SAPI, CGI, something else). All that matters. setlocale changes in one thread may cause changes in other PHP threads.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, PHP stores the amount variable as a float, so the problem is when you display that value. 
Try this:

```
<?php    
echo $amount; //21.960000
echo $this->obj_vat->vat; //10.00
$amount= $amount + ( $amount * ( $this->obj_vat->vat / 100 ) );
echo number_format($amount, 2, '.', ',');
```

See a demo here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba34855a2de309c842c7ce678713f4168a852999

Answer (score 0):

Every think is worked fine.

For your information do somthink like this,

```
<?php    
echo $amount; //21.960000
echo $this->obj_vat->vat; //10.00
$amount= $amount + ( $amount * ( $this->obj_vat->vat / 100 ) );
echo (float) $amount; //24.156
?>
```

Comment: This does not work. It still will display ",", if it's set in `LOCALE` settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a local configuration issue, probably caused after installing php-intl recently, which changed it for you unintentionally.

Edit your `/etc/default/locale` file and change the `LC_NUMERIC` line to

`LC_NUMERIC = "en_GB.UTF-8"`

You might want to change any other setting there, then reboot.

Comment: Global php.ini configuration inside a multi-locale app? He already did what you propose here, but wasn't sure is that the right way.

Comment: He wants globally have the numerics to `en_GB` (dot separator). This file sets it globally (and it's not a php.ini file, do a bit of googling)

Comment: And where did he say such a thing? OP already mentioned the site is a multilangual app so I guess the locale details like number formatting should vary.

Comment: Dude, it seems we're not reading the same "This is a multilanguage website. In the spanish version the locale is set to spanish (es_ES), and the decimal separator is ','. That's why is changing.

A solution is to force the LC_NUMERIC to english:" (because he wants a dot separtor... always). BTW, it does not make sense to discuss such an old post. I just had the same problem and solved it this way, this is one of the first entries when you google "PHP decimal separator", and I though it may help further visitors. Have a nice day