# String to float conversion not working php

Tags: php, string, floating-point, double, decimal

I've a string value of the type "x.yy" which I want to convert to double/float.
I've tried `floatval()`, `doubleval()` and float and double type casting as well but it only gives me "X" as the number and ignores the part after decimal i.e ".yy".

```
$duration = "3.08";
echo (float)$duration; // gives 3 and ignores .08
echo floatval($duration); // same as above
```

expected result should be 3.08 with type float.

I've tried solutions already but didn't worked. Can anyone tell me how to get this working ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have the `= 3` on each `echo` line?

Comment: just for demonstration that it echos 3 on execution.

Comment: Have you tried without it?

Comment: With your updated code I get `3.083.08`

Comment: check your local settings and your decimal seperator, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954111/php-change-the-decimal-separator

Comment: Nigel don't know why it doesn't work for me.
FatFreddy let me check it.

Comment: check it with print_r( localeconv());

Comment: @FatFreddy that could not point me to the right direction

Comment: @FatFreddy check the `print_r( localeconv())` response here: https://pasteid.fledix.com/7yba

Comment: [decimal_point] => .  seems to be ok, then i am clueless